# Comparing two sheets. All columns?

Tags: excel

The code below are for comparing two diffrent sheets in one workbook. it compares rows in column A, and it works excelent. Do anyone know how to make it compare rows through all columns (A-M), and not just A? appriciate any help.

```
Sub Compare()
Dim LR As Long
Dim x As Range
Dim xr As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row

Sheets("Ny").Columns("N:N").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Set xr = Sheets("Ny").Range("N2:N" & LR)

With xr
        
        .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Aktuell!$A$2:$M$2000,1,false)),""Bold"","""")"
        .Value = .Value
    
End With

For Each x In xr

    If x.Value = "Bold" Then x.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
    
Next

Sheets("Ny").Columns("N:N").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft



Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(` - am I right in deducing that this formula is to check if the range `Aktuell!$A$2:$M$2000` contains the A value?

Comment: I believe so. I didnt write this formula myself, so im not entirely sure. If i change =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Aktuell!$A$2:$M$2000,1,false)) to =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,Aktuell!$B$2:$M$2000,1,false)) it compares the rows in column B. but i cant make it work over all columns.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `Countif()` rather than `IsNa(Vlookup())` on each individual cell to check whether it should go bold.
It also uses `Worksheetfunction` to get the result in a single `If` Statement rather than writing formulas in the worksheet then deleting them afterwards, all evaluation done in the vba.

```
Sub Compare()
Dim LR As Long
Dim x as Range
Dim rngcheck As Range 'range to be checked

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rngCheck = Sheets("Ny").Range("A2:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row)

With WorksheetFunction
    For Each x In rngCheck
        If .Countif(Sheets("Aktuell").Range("A2:M2000"), x.value) > 0 Then x.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
    Next
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This didnt work unfortunately. It just made everything bold from A2 to M2000.

Comment: Then I'd guess every cell value in that range would be contained somewhere in `Sheets("Aktuell").Range("A2:M2000")`. By 'check multiple columns' did you mean you wanted a multi-column match, a matching whole row?